# How do I prevent unauthorized attempts to access a specific file type?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

This is really a couple of questions about preventing unauthorized attempts to access a specific file type. Here go the questions:

1. How do I prevent users from directly requesting a type of file? Do I write an HTTP handler?
2. After preventing a direct download, can my app still explicitly serve that file type? How?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what, exactly, you are trying to accomplish? Some context is needed to really help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to:

1. Put all your tif files in a non publicly accessible location
2. Create an IHttpHandler to serve these tif files based on authentication (or whatever limitation you choose).
3. (Optional) Set up a rewrite rule so that all tif requests go through your IHttpHandler. This creates nice URL's again.

Comment: Note that there is no bullet-proof way to prevent people from requesting a file while allowing your app on their machine to request it.

Comment: There is... you're web app could be in c:\inetpub\wwwroot, whereas your tif files could be in c:\webdata\. Then it is just a matter of setting appropriate application pool permissions. At least, I thought you could do it that way? Of course I could be misinterpreting the initial question :)

Comment: I think SLaks means that if you hard-code a key in your client app, users will find it.

Comment: but... when the browser renders the image, it can still be copied and taken from the browser.  once it's rendered (even through an iHttpHandler), it is considered a physical fine (even if it's not).

Comment: Hmmm; all valid points. I interpreted the question that they were simply wanting to prevent unauthorised requests to a file type (i.e. they must have passed authentication or something). Could be wrong of course.

Comment: @Paul Mason - You are correct. Just prevent unauthorized attempts to access a specific file type.